# Simplifying vector sum with dot product and norms

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, vector-analysis

I have a vector which is defined as
$$
r(x)=\left( 
\begin{array}{c}
a_1\\a_2\\a_3
\end{array}
\right) u(x,y)+
\left( 
\begin{array}{c}
b_1\\b_2\\b_3
\end{array}
\right) D_xu(x,y)+
\left( 
\begin{array}{c}
c_1\\c_2\\c_3
\end{array}
\right) D_yu(x,y).
$$
My goal is to find the euclidean norm to this equation, which I obtain as
$$
|r(x)|=\sqrt{|a|^2u^2+|b|^2u_x^2+|c|^2u_y^2+ 2u u_y a \centerdot c+2u u_x a\cdot b+2u_xu_yb \cdot c}
$$
The internals of the square root look suspiciously like the standard
$$\left(a u+b u_x+c u_y\right){}^2 =
a^2 u^2+b^2 u_x^2+c^2 u_y^2+2 a b u u_x+2 a c u u_y+2 b c u_x u_y
$$
 but I can't see how we can have both the dot product and the squared euclidean norm in the same equation. I can only assume there's a simple trick that I'm missing which will make this work properly?

Thanks!

Comment: The dot product of a vector with itself is the square of its norm. Seems compatible to me on the face of it.

Comment: amd is correct. Your question is odd, as the Euclidean norm is exactly the square root of the dot product with itself, so of course that is what you see. The only potential error I see is the presence of $u_y$. As you are showing $u$ as a function $u(x)$ dependent on $x$ only, One would expect $u_y = D_y u = 0$. But maybe you just used a poor notation, instead of really meaning that $u$ depended on $x$ only.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I have butchered the notation. I did mean $u(\mathbf{x})=u(x,y)$, so that the partial differentials are valid.

Comment: Yes, all credit to amd — $|r(x,y)|=\sqrt{ (au + bu_x + cu_y) \cdot (au + bu_x + cu_y)}$ is identical to the form I derived above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credit should go to [amd](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/265466/amd), since their comment above pointed me in the right direction. 
$$
|\hat{r}(x,y)|^2=\hat{r}(x,y) \cdot \hat{r}(x,y)
$$
and thus
$$
|\hat{r}(x,y)|=\sqrt{\hat{r}(x,y) \cdot \hat{r}(x,y)} 
$$